# Unable to pass string array as parameter to HttpGet in Web API

Tags: c#, arrays, rest

My endpoint is decorated like

```
[HttpGet("{data}")]
public async Task<MyObj> Get([FromQuery]List<string> data)
```

And I call this via

```
https:.........../api/Learning/one,other,hello
```

My `data` list is empty and I do not understand what I need to change.

I assume I can pass a string array as a parameter to an `HttpGet` endpoint?

Comment: See the marked duplicate. The answer is the same whether you use a string or you use an integer.

Comment: 1) `FromQuery` reads from the query string - You need `FromRoute` 2) I think you'll have to split the string yourself